# What is the "Endurance Cache" feature in my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins, shared-hosting

I noticed this new wordpress version I'm running has a "Endurance Cache" option at the bottom of the "Settings > General" page.

That is caching all of the changes I'm doing on css. So whenever I update something the changes don't reflect on the browser instantaneously.

I'm wondering if that's wordpress native or if I can remove it.

I'm using wordpress 4.8.1.

My other website that has an older wordpress version doesn't have it.

It's not listed as an installed plugin. So that I don't think it is.

I'm using thesis theme.

thanks

Comment: old question I realize but https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers is helpful for newer users to know what to do when someone answers their question (noting there is no accepted answer here, would be nice to know which solution worked best for OP)

Answer (score 13):

It is a plugin installed by hostgator. They install two plugins "Endurance Browser Cache" and "Endurance Page Cache."

You can disable the Endurance Page Cache plugin by going to "Plugins" > "Must-Use" then locating the "Endurance Page Cache" plugin and clicking "disable."

The other plugin called "Endurance Browser Cache" does not have a disable button.

I hope this works for you. I do not know if hostgator will remove these plugins for you.

Comment: Even though it has enabled/disable button it never works, creepy!

Answer (score 11):

Here is the easiest solution I found for it:

1. Log into your Cpanel and click on Files.
2. Choose your domain/subdomain and click on the WP-Content.
3. Click on the "mu-plugins".
4. Rename the File "endurance-page-cache.php" to "endurance-page-cache.php.old"
5. Create a blank file there and name it "endurance-page-cache.php"

That's it, problem solved. And if you ever in the future want to activate it again, simply delete the blank file that you created and remove the word "old" from the original file name.

Comment: This worked for me.  Hostmonster does this as well, FYI.  We had no idea this was going on and it caused serious problems for a client.  I've been slowly moving away from Hostmonster, and this is the final straw.

Comment: I just saw this plugin as a "Must Use" plugin on my website (HostMonster), which is what got me here. I did as suggested. Question: SHould I delete the plugin listed in the plugins in WordPress? Or should I just leave it since the file has been co-opted with a blank file?

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. It's a plugin installed by hostgator.
Unfortunately it's not listed in the wordpress plugins area.
So I needed to request them to remove it.

Comment: Bluehost also installs this plugin, just FYI.

Comment: I confirm that Bluehost installs it too.

Comment: Bluehost and Hostgator are both owned by the same crappy parent company EIG.

Answer (score 1):

This caching plugin was installed most probably by your hosting provider. A brief and quick solution to the problem:

1. Instal WP File Manager Plugin:
   https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager/
2. Go to the plugin settings and head over to htdocs/WP Content/mu-plugins
3. Find the file "endurance-page-cache.php"  and either rename it for temporal deactivation or delete it altogether if you want to get
   rid of this plugin.
4. If this was the only file in the folder mu-plugins, you may as well delete the folder mu-plugins. "MU" stands for "Must Use". Sometimes a hosting provider or a developer might install their custom code for a site project as an mu-plugin so it doesn't get uninstalled by their customer.
5. Uninstall WP File Manager Plugin as it's not needed anymore. Better look on how to access your site files using C-panel if provided by your hosting provider or via FTP (like Filezilla) rather than a plugin.
6. Get a proper caching plugin. (Give Cachify plugin a go - it is free).

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of Endurance Page Cache or whatever other mu-plugin that you don't need, you can now use [Mu Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mu-manager/).
After activation Go to Plugins => Must Use, and deactivate the unneeded mu-plugins that you don't need. It will be like deactivating standard plugins.
Of course, you should know which mu-plugin are not needed. In the case of Endurance Page Cache, I think you never need it if you have a proper caching plugin.

If you prefer to use FTP it will be not enough to rename the mu-plugin, because it will run the same. You need to delete it or replace the extension .php with something else.